# Simpy: don't understand why my simulation never ends

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I'm trying to simulate a game of Counter Strike. Basically I have two teams with different players (all the players are identical for now) and I want them to "fight" and when all the players on one team are dead, the simulation should end.

I'm trying to understand why the simulation I'm running never ends. I feel like I'm misunderstanding some core element of simpy but I don't really know what.

All of the process and simpy related code are in main.py and player.py. 
I'm trying to get my simulation to end once every player has "died".

Basically I want every player to be a process that constantly checks their surrounding area (the node they are in which is represented by the Hotspot class) to see if there are any enemies. If there are any enemies they will choose one at random and "attack" them. Once all of the players from any team have health below 0 the simulation should end and the team that won should increment their win count by 1.

EDIT: Also of note, when I ran it through pdb it seemed like none of the player's health were decreasing and that the play method wasn't being run.

EDIT 2: I don't think all of the code needs to be read to find the problem, I think it's mostly in the main and player files but I'm not 100% sure because the code loops infinitely without error

Here is my code

#### main.py

```
from player import Player
from game_map import Game_Map
from team import Team
from sides import Sides
import simpy
import pdb


def main():
  team_a = Team("Team_A", Sides.CT)
  team_b = Team("Team_B", Sides.T)
  gmap = Game_Map()
  gmap.spawn_team(team_a)
  gmap.spawn_team(team_b)

  env = simpy.Environment()
  for team in (team_a, team_b):
    for player in team.players:
      env.process(player.play(env))

  env.run(until=round(team_a, team_b, env))

def round(team_a, team_b, env):

  while True:
    if team_a.all_dead():
      team_b.round_wins += 1
      print team_b
      env.exit()
    if team_b.all_dead():
      team_a.round_wins += 1
      print team_a
      env.exit()



if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

#### player.py

```
import simpy
from sides import Sides
import numpy as np
import pdb

class Player(object):
  """ Class that represents a CSGO player"""

  def __init__(self, steam_id, team, acc, hs_percentage):
    # the player's id
    self.steam_id = steam_id
    # percentage of shots that hit, accuracy
    self.acc = acc
    # percentage of hits that hit the head
    self.hs_percentage = hs_percentage

    # the team 
    self.team = team
    # the player's health, this changes when the teams "fight"
    self.health = 100

    # the current hotspot that the player is in
    self.current_location = 0



    # if the player is alive or dead
    self.is_alive = True



  def play(self, env):
    """Process that simulates the player's actions. This is run once every round until
    the round is over"""
    while(self.is_alive):
      target = self.choose_target()
      if target == -1:
        continue
        yield env.timeout(5)
      else:
        target.inflict_self(self.determine_damage())        
        yield env.timeout(5)


  def determine_damage(self):
    """The amount of damage the player will inflict on the enemy"""
    return 27

  def choose_target(self):
    """Choose a target to attack from the enemies in the hotspot"""

    # 1 - side converts 0 to 1 and 1 to 0
    enemy_list = self.current_location.players[1 - self.team.side]
    num_enemies = len(enemy_list)

    # if there are no enemies currently in the same location of the player
    # simply return 0
    if num_enemies == 0:
      return -1

    # pick an enemy randomly from the list of enemies and return their object
    return enemy_list[np.random.random_integers(0, num_enemies - 1)]


  def get_side(self):
    return self.team.side

  def inflict_self(self, damage):
    """Inflict damage onto own class. If damage moves health below 0, mark the 
    player as "Dead" and remove them from the map"""
    self.health = self.health - damage
    if self.health <= 0:
      self.current_location.players[self.team.side].remove(self)
      self.is_alive = False


  def __str__(self):
    return "Steam id: {0}\tIs Alive: {1}\tCurrent Location: {2}".format(self.steam_id, self.is_alive, self.current_location)


def tests():
  return

if __name__ == "__main__":
  tests()
```

#### game_map.py

```
import networkx as nx
from hotspot import Hotspot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
class Game_Map(object):
  """ Generic map that represents general outline of all counter strike maps"""

  def __init__(self):
    self.graph = nx.Graph()
    self.spawns = [Hotspot()]
    self.graph.add_node(self.spawns[0])

  def add_team(team):
    #side = team.side
    # side is 0 because for testing the simulation
    # we are only using one node
    side = 0
    for player in team.players:
      self.spawns[side].move_into(player)

  def spawn_team(self, team):
    for player in team.players:
      self.spawns[0].move_into(player)


  def draw(self):
    nx.draw(self.graph)
    plt.show()

def tests():
  """Tests to see that Game_Map class works properly"""

  # initialize the map
  gmap = Game_Map()
  gmap.draw()



# if this module is being run explicitly from the command line
# run tests to assure that this module is working properly
if __name__ == "__main__":
  tests()
```

#### hotspot.py

```
import simpy
from player import Player
from team import Team
from sides import Sides
class Hotspot(object):
  """Hotspots are the representation for different areas of the map. This is where players 'fight'."""

  def __init__(self):
    self.players = [[], []]


  def move_into(self, player):
    side = player.get_side()
    self.players[side].append(player)
    player.current_location = self

    return 1


  def __eq__(self, other):
    return id(self) == id(other)

  def __hash__(self):
    return id(self)


def tests():
  """Tests to see that hotspot works properly"""
  hotspot_list = []
  for i in range(5):
    hotspot_list.append(Hotspot())

  for spot in hotspot_list:
    team_a = Team("team_a", Sides.CT)
    team_b = Team("team_b", Sides.T)
    spot.move_into(Player(1, team_a, .5, .5))
    spot.move_into(Player(1, team_b, .5, .5))

    print "Hotspot id = {0}".format(id(spot))
    for team in spot.players:
      for player in team:
        print "player = {0} in team {1}".format(player, player.team)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  tests()
```

#### sides.py

```
class Sides(object):
  """Enum object, simply represents CT (Counter Terrorists) as 0 and 
  T (Terrorists) as 1"""
  CT, T = range(2)
```

#### team.py

```
from player import Player
class Team(object):
  """Class that holds critical team information"""
  def __init__(self, name, side):
    self.round_wins = 0
    self.players = []
    self.name = name
    self.side = side
    self.generate_team()

  def all_dead(self):
    count = 0
    for player in self.players:
      if player.is_alive == False:
        count += 1
    if count == 5:
      return True
    else: 
      return False



  def __str__(self):
    rep = "Team: {0}, Round Wins: {1}\n".format(self.name, self.round_wins)
    for player in self.players:
      rep += player.__str__() + '\n'

    return rep


  def generate_team(self):
    for i in range(5):
      self.players.append(Player(1, self, .5, .2))

  __rep__ = __str__
```

#### requirements.txt

```
decorator==3.4.2
matplotlib==1.4.3
mock==1.0.1
networkx==1.9.1
nose==1.3.6
numpy==1.9.2
pyparsing==2.0.3
python-dateutil==2.4.2
pytz==2015.2
scipy==0.15.1
simpy==3.0.7
six==1.9.0
```

Comment: I think you're going to have a hard time getting folks to read through all of this code and figure out what is wrong. Can you try and narrow down the problem?

Comment: In game_map add_team, you only use side 0 - doesn't that mean that all your players end up on the same team? This would explain why there's no damage being inflicted?

Comment: That's not a problem because I am only using one node. There are two times where the side is needed, when I first add players to the map before the simulation starts (where I keep side 0 for this case because I'm not testing moving between nodes ie Hotspot at this point and I am just adding everyone to the same node to test the combat portion) and when players are added to their respective list in the Hotspot class (where it matters, this is where players look for enemies to "fight".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `round()` function is the culprit:

```
env.run(until=round(team_a, team_b, env))

def round(team_a, team_b, env):

  while True:
    if team_a.all_dead():
      team_b.round_wins += 1
      print team_b
      env.exit()
    if team_b.all_dead():
      team_a.round_wins += 1
      print team_a
      env.exit()
```

The function contains an infinite loop without any yields.  This means it never returns and `env.run()` isn’t even executed.

Comment: Do you have any advice on how I can make it yield without ending the simulation?

Comment: yield env.timeout(x) inside the loop would be a good start.  As someone else already suggested, you should maybe work through SimPy’s tutorial, examples and topical guides.  http://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling this might be an infinite loop:

```
while(self.is_alive):
  target = self.choose_target()
  if target == -1:
    continue
    yield env.timeout(5)
```

You probably want to yield before the `continue` (which is unneeded anyway).

Comment: Thank you, I fixed that but the simulation still never finishes

Comment: @vicg: Interrupt the program in the debugger and see where it hangs.

Comment: It hangs when I hit env.run(until=round(team_a, team_b, env))

Comment: You really need to apply some basic debugging skills here. If you're not comfortable with the debugger, try inserting `print` statements into crucial functions, in particular the `play` method, to get some output on what's going on.

Comment: That's the thing, the environment never seems to run the play method, (nothing gets printed from it).  It simply loops on the run method forever. I think I'm simply misunderstanding how the simpy module works.

Comment: Read this and work through the example: http://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/simpy_intro/